# NSIS build does not install the Electron application on Windows. The installer exits silently and produces a 1620 error

Tags: node.js, installation, electron, electron-builder

I'm building an Electron app using electron-builder. The build process produces a setup.exe file, but when I launch the setup process, the installer gets to around 50% completion and then exits.

The only file that is in the installation directory,`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Application-Name`, after running setup is the uninstaller.exe file.

The Mac version installs successfully, and the unpacked EXE file works as expected on Windows.

I have tried this on Windows 7 and Windows 8 with the same results. I have also tried setting the `oneClick` property to true and false without any success with either option.

```
{
  "name": "Application-Name",
  "author": "Company",
  "description": "Publication Archive",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./",
  "main": "./src/electron.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "connected-react-router": "^6.5.0",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "preelectron-pack:win": "npm run build && cp ./src/db.js ./build/db.js && cp ./src/electron.js ./build/electron.js",
    "electron-pack:win": "cross-env DEBUG=electron-builder build --win"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.electron.application-name",
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "icons",
      "output": "release-builds"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "icon": "icons/winapp.png"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": false
    },
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "db/**/*",
      "public/**/*"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^5.0.6",
    "electron-builder": "^20.44.4",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
}
```

*Installer log file contents:*

```
=== Verbose logging started: 7/9/2019  13:50:53  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7601.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (18:B0) [13:50:53:991]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (18:B0) [13:50:53:991]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (18:98) [13:50:54:030]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (18:98) [13:50:54:030]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (18:98) [13:50:54:030]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: Application-Name Setup 0.1.0.exe
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (18:98) [13:50:54:033]: Note: 1: 2203 2: Application-Name Setup 0.1.0.exe 3: -2147286960 
MSI (c) (18:98) [13:50:54:034]: MainEngineThread is returning 1620
=== Verbose logging stopped: 7/9/2019  13:50:54 ===
```

I expect that the result of running the installer would be that the application is installed in the default location or that there would be a more helpful error message, but I can't seem to find the right combo of options to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation. New installation is now possible by manually removing the application. You can remove applications from Control Panel> Programs> Uninstall a program.